# minipage subcaption text not working

Tags: minipage, subcaption, text

I am writing my thesis in memoir class. The subcaption texts are not appearing under the minipage content. Its appearing when I am running the following code, but in my thesis the subcaption text are not appearing. I am using minipage to put images side by side. Many thanks in advance.

```
 \documentclass{memoir}
    \newsubfloat{figure}

    \begin{document}

        \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
        hello...
        \subcaption{packing of particles}
        \end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
        hello...
        \subcaption{Output}
        \end{minipage}
        \caption{Python code}
        \label{lst:python_code}
        \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

The minipage part of my thesis is as follows:

```
\begin{figure}[H] \small
\centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{.35\linewidth}
\centering
{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures8/Image_1.png}}
\subcaption{packing of particles}\label{fig:10a}
\end{minipage}%
~~~~~
\begin{minipage}[b]{.25\linewidth}
\centering
{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures8/Image_2.png}}
\subcaption{FEA mesh}\label{fig:10b}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Plastic energy dissipation density vs strain (6S and 6L denote 6 wt \% small CSR and 6 wt \% large CSR particle modified epoxies respectively)}
\label{fig:8three}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but do you expect us to just guess what you did differently in your thesis? Make a copy of your thesis, and reduce it to a minimal example that *does* demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I agree with @TorbjørnT., how could anybody offer help with basically a single sentence to show the problem...

Comment: Hi Torbjorn, I didn't do anything different in my thesis. I meant to say that when I am running the above code the subcaption texts are appearing. But when I am putting texts in my thesis its not appearing though I am doing the same. I can not post the code of my thesis as the preamble is too large!

Comment: I have added the minipage part of my thesis

Comment: That was why I said reduce it to a minimal example. Remove as much as you can from the preamble, until you’re left with the smallest complete document needed to  demonstrante the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rather comment than answer ...

your code works as expected. it gives (with use of the package `graphicx` for example images):

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsubfloat{figure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\subcaption{packing of particles}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\subcaption{Output}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Python code}
\label{lst:python_code}
\end{figure}

\end{document}}
```

please clarify, what is your problem. illustrate it with image which you obtain with your code.

Comment: many thanks zarko. I just realised that I had \captionsetup[subfloat]{format=myformat} in my preamble, which was probably stopping the subcaption text to appear after (a), (b) etc.

Comment: @Tasnuva So it seems that you have used `\newsubfloat{figure}` and the subcaption package. This sounds like a bad idea to me, one should either use `\newsubfloat{figure}` and use the sub-captioning stuff from memoir, or use the subcaption package, but not both.